# Is It Possible To Track GPU Performance Increase?

Tags: centos, performance, video, gpu, high-performance

CentOS7

I'm about to upgrade my gpu.  Before I take action I am curious if there are any tests I can run on the cli that will track the performance of my current gpu so I can compare to the new gpu?

For example, with increased performance of hard drives I use `hdparm` curious to see if there is something like this for graphics cards and my new gpu is going to be a massive upgrade I'd like to document the performance difference if possible.

Comment: Why would hardware reviews wouldn't do it so you need to always track that ?

Comment: I only answer the question when I am being paid now a days. I need to eat too.

Answer (score 2):

You can benchmark some pc component, including GPU by:

```
Unigine 3D engine
```

Got to the vendor website, download, install and run it.

Comment: Looks like `Unigine Superposition` ( https://benchmark.unigine.com/superposition ) is the best real native benchmark on Linux, perhaps the only one apart from the old Valley and Heaven. It's a well-known one in Windows and the Phoronix Test Suite do use it. The best would be to launch a very GPU-intensive game though, but reproductibily is subpar if not correctly done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the benchmarking tool GL Mark 2 for this:

```
sudo apt-get install glmark2
```

Run it by typing the follow on terminal:

```
glmark2
```

Comment: This and your other 2 answers were quite clearly copied from [howtoforge.com](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-gpu-benchmark). Can you provide some attribution to the source you used?

Comment: For more infos, chech the github page: https://github.com/glmark2/glmark2

Comment: Same as glxgears, glmark is not a real benchmark nor will make the GPU works a lot.